# Goldstine theorem

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, duality-theorems

Given the embedding $j:X\to X''$ defined by,

$$j=(x\mapsto(\phi\mapsto\phi(x)))\,,$$

according to my interpretation of [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstine_theorem), *Goldstine theorem* says the following:

$$\overline{jB_X}^{weak\ast}=B_{X''}$$

with $B_Y$ the closed unit ball of $Y$. But I weak $\ast$ topology is defined on $X'$ right? So how can we take the closure with respect to this topology of elements of $X''$?

Comment: $X'' = (X')'$ is also a dual.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla So the correct formulation is $\overline{jB_X}^{\sigma(E'',E')}=B_{X''}$?

Comment: Yes, being more explicit is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The weak $\ast$ topology used in the Goldstine theorem is not the normal weak $\ast$ topology of $X$ defined on $X'$. It is the weak $\ast$ topology of $X'$ defined on the dual of $X'$, i.e. $X''$.

*Goldstine theorem* can thus be formulated as: 
$$\overline{jB_X}^{\sigma(E'',E')}=B_{X''}$$